# building MIN-Heap in c++

Tags: c++, heapsort

I am trying to implement min-heap just by reversing the propeties of max_heapify int the code but I am getting a segmentation fault(core dumped) during execution.What I know somewhere the code is accessing a memory to which it does not has access to. What is the problem with this code?

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

void min_heapify(int a[], int i, int n)
{
    int l,r,smallest,loc;
    l=(2*i);
    r=(2*i+1);

    if((l<=n) && (a[l]>a[i]))
        smallest=i;
    else
        smallest=l;

    if((r<=n) && (a[smallest]>a[r]))
        smallest=r;

    if(smallest != i)
    {
        loc=a[i];
        a[i]=a[smallest];
        a[smallest]=loc;

        min_heapify(a,smallest,n);
    }   
}

void build_min_heap(int a[], int n)
{
    for(int k=n/2;k>=1;k--)
    {
        min_heapify(a,k,n);
    }
}

void heapsort(int a[], int n)
{
    build_min_heap(a,n);

    int temp,i;
    for(i=n;i>=2;i--)
    {
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[1];
        a[1]=temp;

        min_heapify(a,1,i-1);
    }
}

   main()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the number of elements\n";
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        cout<<"Enter the numbers\n";
        int a[n];
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
             cin>>a[i];
        heapsort(a,n);
        cout<<"::::::::::::::::The Sorted List Is::::::::::::::\n";
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
        return 0;
      }
```

Comment: In C++, only `a[0]` to `a[n-1]` are available for `int a[n];` and you must not access `a[n]`.

Comment: You should at least learn enough debugging skills to find which line is causing the problem. Once you can do that, it might be pretty easy to see why it is a problem.

Comment: Side note: `int a[n];` is not standard C++ when `n` is not a constant expression.

Comment: Changing `int a[n];` to `int a[n+1];` coudl't avoid Segmentation Fault.

Comment: just a beginner. I will surely learn debugging.Thanks.

Comment: I tried removing **<=** to just **<** but it did not help.

Comment: also tried to make **n** constant but recieved segmentation fault.

Comment: Technically that's not a valid C++ program, the `main` function is not declared correct. It must always be declared explicitly to return an `int`.